# How to disable/hide a Partial View based on IList values?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to disable or hide a PartialView based on values inside two different ILists. Both of these lists are stored in two Session variables, `_UserRoleList` and `_PartialRoleList`.

The list contents of `_UserRoleList` are of type `User` which contains the following properties:

- UserName
- RoleID
- RoleDescription
- SID

The list contents of `_PartialRoleList` are of type `PartialRole` which contains the following properties:

- PartialName
- RoleID
- AccessLevelID
- AccessLevelDescription

### Case 1 - Disable all input controls inside the Partial View:

Disable **ALL** input controls (textboxes, listboxes, checkboxes, dropdownlists) on the specified PartialView (with an `id` of "frmClientDetails") if a `RoleID` of **3** is found in both session lists.

### Case 2 - Set all input controls to read-only inside the Partial View:

All input controls (textboxes, listboxes, checkboxes, dropdownlists) on the specified PartialView (with an `id` of "frmClientDetails") should have their read-only attribute set to true if a`RoleID` of **2** is found in both session lists.

**Question**:
Would it be better to retrieve the two lists and then use a jQuery [`.each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to loop through and search for equality on the `RoleID` fields? Would another option be to use Razor? If pseudo code could be provided, that would be a great help.

**Controller snippet**:

```
public ViewResult Index()   /* Master View, starting point of application */
{
    int userID;
    IList<User> userRoleList;
    IList<PartialRole> partialRoleList;
    WindowsIdentity identity = null;

    identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

    userRoleList = _homeService.GetUserDetails(identity.User.ToString());

    userID = userRoleList.First().ID;

    partialRoleList = _homeService.GetPartialDetails(userID);

    if (Session["_UserRoleList"] == null)
    {
        HttpContext.Session.Contents.Add("_UserRoleList", userRoleList);
    }

    if (Session["_PartialRoleList"] == null)
    {
        HttpContext.Session.Contents.Add("_PartialRoleList", partialRoleList);
    }

    return View();
}
```

**Original View - ClientDetails.cshtml**:

```
@using InvoiceManagement.Models
@model InvoiceClient

@{
InvoiceCreditNoteViewModel viewModel = new InvoiceCreditNoteViewModel();
viewModel.Client = Model;

ViewBag.Title = "Client Details";

 List<User> userRoleList = Session["_UserRoleList"] != null ? (List<User>)Session["_UserRoleList"] : null;
 List<PartialRole> partialRoleList = Session["_PartialRoleList"] != null ? (List<PartialRole>)Session["_PartialRoleList"] : null;
}

@section scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[type=radio][name=optionInvoiceCreditNote]').change(function () {
            if (this.value == 'invoice') {
                $("#InvoiceGrid").show();
                $("#CreditNoteGrid").hide();
            }
            else if (this.value == 'creditNote') {
                $("#InvoiceGrid").hide();
                $("#CreditNoteGrid").show();
            }
        });

        $('#showActive').click(function (e) {
            if($(this).prop('checked') === true){
                var url = '@Url.Action("FilterActiveOnlyAgreements")';

                $.get(url, { invoiceClientID: '@Model.ID' }, function (result) {
                    $('#agreementGrid').html(result);
                });
            }
            else {
                var url = '@Url.Action("FilterAllAgreements")';

                $.get(url, { invoiceClientID: '@Model.ID' }, function (result) {
                    $('#agreementGrid').html(result);
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
}

@Html.Partial("ClientDetailsFormPartial", viewModel.Client)

@if (viewModel.Client.ID > 0)
{
    @Html.Partial("ClientDetailsAgreementPartial")
    @Html.Partial("InvoiceCreditNoteContainerPartial", viewModel)
}
```

**Partial View - ClientDetailsFormPartial**:

```
@using InvoiceManagement.Models
@model InvoiceClient

@using (@Html.BeginForm("ClientDetails", "Client", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "frmClientDetails" }))
{
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <h2>Client Details</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2" style="min-height: 70px;">
                <a href="/client/SearchForClient" class="btn btn-default" style="position: absolute; bottom: 15px">Search New Client</a>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-2" style="min-height: 70px;">
                <div class="input-group" style="top: 21px">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="client-ID">Client ID</span>
                    @Html.TextBox("ID", Model.ID, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
                </div>
                <div class="has-error">
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ID, String.Empty, new { @class = "help-block" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-3" style="min-height: 70px;">
                <div class="input-group" style="top: 21px">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="accounting-ID">Accounting ID</span>
                    @if (Model.AID == null && Model.ID == 0)
                    {
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AID, new { @class = "form-control" }) }
                    else
                    {
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AID, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" }) }
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="padding-top: 22px;">
                <div class="has-error">
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AID, String.Empty, new { @class = "help-block" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-7">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="client-name">Client Name</span>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.InvoiceClientName, new { @class = "form-control", @name = "InvoiceClientName" })
                </div>
                <div class="has-error">
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.InvoiceClientName, String.Empty, new { @class = "help-block" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="default-tax-code-1">Default Tax Code 1</span>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DefaultTaxCodeID1, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.PopulateDefaultTaxCode1, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "default-tax-code1-ID", @name = "defaultTaxCodeID1" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="default-tax-code-2">Default Tax Code 2</span>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DefaultTaxCodeID2, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.PopulateDefaultTaxCode2, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "default-tax-code2-ID", @name = "defaultTaxCodeID2" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="status">Status</span>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StatusID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.PopulateStatus, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "status-ID", @name = "statusID" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-7">
                @if (Model == null || Model.ID == 0)
                {
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add New Client</button>
                }
                else
                {
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Update Existing Client</button>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `disabled` controls will not post back, its pointless to generate all that extra html, and since `readonly` controls cannot be edited, again it seems pointless to generate all that extra html and then send it all back unchanged to the server when you submit your form.

A better approach, performance wise would be to have 2 partial views (say) `_ClientDetails.cshtml` and `_ReadOnlyClientDetails.cshtml`. The first would contain your form and its editable controls and submit button, and the second would contain only the text values of your properties, for example

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.InvoiceClientName)
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.InvoiceClientName)
```

Then in your controller method that generates you main view, set a view model property (or `ViewBag` property) to indicate which partial to display, for example

```
ViewBag.IsReadonly = true; // or omit depending on your logic
```

and in the main view

```
@if(ViewBag.IsReadonly)
{
    @Html.Partial("_ReadOnlyClientDetails", viewModel.Client)
}
else
{
    @Html.Partial("_ClientDetails", viewModel.Client)
}
```

Side note: Everything between you first `@{ ... }` except `ViewBag.Title = "Client Details";` belongs in the controller method, not the view. And to do something like `viewModel.Client = Model;` makes no sense at all. Your view should be `@model InvoiceCreditNoteViewModel` and since you're not passing a model to the view, then `viewModel.Client = Model;` would not make sense anyway since its always `null`.

Its also not clear why your using `Session`. The code in your controller should be something like

```
IList<User> userRoleList = _homeService.GetUserDetails(identity.User.ToString());
int userID = userRoleList.First().ID;
IList<PartialRole> partialRoleList = _homeService.GetPartialDetails(userID)
List<int> values = new List<int>(){ 2, 3 };
if (userRoleList.Any(x => values.Contains(x.RoleID)) && partialRoleList.Any(x => values.Contains(x.RoleID)))
{
    ViewBag.IsReadonly = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Stephen. I completely understand and agree with the unnecessary HTML being generated. My original purpose was to use the same views that I had and, if their controls were to be read-only/disabled, the form would never `POST`. It is for simply granting an admin read-write access to the data whereas a regular user would be read-only and a guest disabled (partial view does not show up).

Comment: My model `InvoiceCreditNoteViewModel` contains two different models - `Client` and `Agreement` (the name that I used definitely needs to be reworked). I created it as the partials within the master view required different models. I chose to use `Session` as the two lists, `_UserRoleList` and `_PartialRoleList` contains the information for each user and their associated privileges to view each individual partial. I need the lists to be extracted throughout different points in the web applications life cycle (3+ master views with 12+ partial views)